# what's in the left part of buf after fgets()?

Tags: c, input, buffer, fgets

I hope to know what will be in the left part of buf after fgets() been exacted. For example:
`char buf[100];

 fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);`
If one line has just 10 characters + '\n', then what will be in the left part of buf (from but[12] to buf[99])?
If execute fgets() twice, will the second input cover the first input to buf?

Comment: fgets() null terminates the input if the input is less than sizeof(buf). The remaining data in the buf is not changed. It starts filling buf from buf[0] each time you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `fgets` reads data it changes one element of the buffer at a time (simplifying assumption) until it reaches the limit or it finds a terminator in the input. All other elements in the buffer *remain the same* as before calling `fgets` (thus, they might have random data or they might leak previously read info).

Comment: "If a read error occurs during the operation, the array contents are
indeterminate and a null pointer is returned" C11 7.21.7.2 3

Answer (score 1):

```
#define SIZE 100
...

char buf[SIZE];
```

`fgets` reads at most  `SIZE - 1` characters from the given file stream and stores them in `buf`. The produced character string is always NULL-terminated. Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case `buf` will contain that newline character. The left of data remains unchanged and it will contain whatever it was holding earlier ,it may be random data or anything left in the memory.And this is validated by the C standard below :

From the C11 standard:-

> **7.21.7.2 The fgets function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of
>   characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into
>   the array pointed to by **s**. No additional characters are read after
>   a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null
>   character is written immediately after the last character read into
>   the array.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The fgets function returns s if successful. **If end-of-file is
>   encountered and no characters have been read into the array, the
>   contents of the array remain unchanged** and a null pointer is
>   returned. **If a read error occurs during the operation, the array
>   contents are indeterminate and a null pointer is returned.**

Emphasis mine :)

Now the second question :-

```
If execute fgets() twice, will the second input cover the first input to buf?
```

If by cover the second input you mean overwrite then yes ,obviously it will overwrite the first input ,you can execute this yourself and see.